# I am unable to import packages into my python files

Tags: python, pip, python-requests-html

I am pretty new with python and I have been running into an issue where I pip install a package, but then pycharm says that the package is not installed.
So far I have been able to get around this by just having pycharm install it for me. Now when I am trying to install requests-html, the install works fine, however, whenever I try to import requests_html, I get an error telling me that the package cannot be found. I did some digging through my files and found that it was installed under site packages under a folder called Python311 however, it was not installed under the site-packages folder in venv. I have no idea if this has anything to do with the issue but thought it might.

Now when I am trying to install requests-html, the install works fine, however, whenever I try to import requests_html, I get an error telling me that the package cannot be found. I did some digging through my files and found that it was installed under site packages under a folder called Python311 however, it was not installed under the site-packages folder in venv. I have no idea if this has anything to do with the issue but thought it might. The error message that Pycham displays 'No module named 'requests_html':3'. I have tried reinstalling the package to no luck.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. And you should provide enough debugging details. How did you install the package or run your code? You said PyCharm and venv. Did you create requirements.txt or setup.py properly?

Comment: Hey @mmelancon11, it looks like you need to set the env you want to activate prior to insallting into that env, and these envs may be tied to your specific projects. Check this out: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#existing-environment

Comment: how did you install the package ?